# Getting random yet consistent data for testing

Tags: data, mocking, random

I have a big codebase yet to be covered with tests and rather limited access to the real data.

The code that needs to be covered is very data dependent. And the data is anything but shallow and trivial.  So I had that naive idea to somehow make the data up. It worked well for simple data sets, but all goes south when there are dependencies in the data to be respected.

The challenge is in generating data with consistent links/dependencies.

Say I have: `Person`, `Account`, `Transaction`, so in the generated data the all foreign keys need to check out:

- for a given `person.accountId` there must be an `Account` with such `Id`

You can easily see how complex this can get quickly.

Is there an approach or algorithm to solve the problem of generating random yet consistent datasets?

Oh, and mind you, with a database schema it's rather easy to generate a random database that conforms to the schema.

But the problem is situated at the next level: the backend API. That does some massaging of the data and the logic of doing it must be reflected in what it yields.

Example: the API should be giving a dataset that is a join of `Person + Account + Transaction` yet being a dataset of its own.

Comment: is copying the real data to dev / local an option?

Comment: it is doable, but i am afraid it could be even more work to maintain and keep in sync with the master copy, on top of it requires much more machinery (local instances of Oracle), so it's a problem of it's own... the goal was to avoid dealing with it and generate data on the fly

Comment: Ah, have you looked into AutoFixture? However like the answer bellow, it may or may not hit your edge cases.  So no prod data and no generated data leaves you with fake data (fakes) to the best of my knowledge.  If you wind up going the manual route look into the builder pattern.  A couple more things, you can mix and match autofixture and fakes, and as far as prod sync goes, it can be an infrequent thing, though the local instances would cost $ obviously.

Comment: A copy of the real data doesn't have to be constantly kept up to date, unless your testing is date/time sensitive.  You just need some data.

Comment: it needs to be updated whenever structural changes done to the master database, which is still in active development

Comment: Well, yes.  But that would be true of any test data, not just test data that originates from production.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of generators.

A Generator creates a specific piece of data, given a few prerequisites and a random number generator.

```
class Layout1 : LayoutGenerator
{

    void generate(Repository, RNG, Generators)
    {
        personID = generators.person(Repository, RNG);
        accountIDs = { generators.account(Repository, RNG, personID ), generators.account(Repository, RNG, personID ) };
        generators.transaction(Repository, RNG, accountIDs[0], 100000);
        generators.transaction(Repository, RNG, accountIDs[1], RNG.between(200, 4000));
        generators.transaction(Repository, RNG, accountIDs[0], RNG.between(100, 4000));
    }
}

class Generators
{
    PersonGenerators = { ... }
    AccountGenerators = { ... }
    TransactionGenerators = { ... }

    person(Repository, RNG) -> PersonGenerators[RNG.(0, PersonGenerators.length-1)].generate(Repository, RNG);

    account(Repository, RNG, personID) -> AccountGenerators[RNG.(0, AccountGenerators.length-1)].generate(Repository, RNG, personID);

    transact(Repository, RNG, accountID, amount) -> TransactionGenerators[RNG.(0, TransactionGenerators.length-1)].generate(Repository, RNG, accountID, amount);
}

class SavingsAccount : AccountGenerator
{
    AccountID generate(Repository, RNG, personID)
    {
        balance = rng.between(0, 5000);
        ...
        account = new SavingsAccount(personID, ......);
        Repository.Add(account);
        return account.id;
    }
}
```

- Need to add a new kind of account, just create a generator for it.
- Need a Person to have 40 accounts, create a layout generator that makes a person with 40 accounts.
- Need to make a person * account * transaction * account * person join? That can be done too and it will use all kinds of person, account, and transaction that can already be generated.
- Need to restrict it? Extend the generators with tags, restrict the random selection to between those with the given tag.
- Need a specific population shape? Just call specific layout generators as many times as needed.
- Need a random but skewed population? Give each generator a weight, when randomly selecting.

Even better the RNG seed is the compressed description of the generated data set. Need it again? just assign the seed on the same code base and generate.

Comment: right, that is the direction in which i've been thinking, sounds easy right?

Comment: Sounds Easy, but anything worth doing has details, and details are the issue of the day. The question isn't can I generate consistent random data. The question is whether that consistent random data looks remotely like correct production-like data in the context of your software. These generators may be over, or under constraining the data generated, they may be making illegal combinations, or never making that esoteric but possible combination. Its these details that are the difference between great and worthless consistent random test data.

Answer (score 3):

A test data generator is nothing but a piece of software which follows the same life cycle rules as any other program:

- first you need to make a rigid specification (like how the data has to look like, how you want to parametrize the generation, which constraints do exists in your environment)
- then you have to code and build that piece that software
- and then you have test, debug and maintain it.

(And of course, usually you repeat these steps in small increments).

This can get as complex as it gets - complex rules lead to a complex generator program. Don't expect a silver bullet to exist for solving this problem.

A helpful tool for building such a generator is **meta data**, like a data model or database schema. If you don't have such a model or schema, build one, and let your generator use that model in a generic fashion. If you have lots of different tables/classes/entities to generator, this can reduce the maintenance effort heavily. But don't expect that you can fulfill every requirement that way. There will be definitely rules and contraints you have to hardcode into the generator.

Answer (score 0):

No structure is better than real data.   Use a copy of the real database.

It's much better to anonymize it. Write a bit of glue code that does this.  (because dev systems tend to be much less secure than production, and you really do not want a database leak. BTDT.

This code would have to be updated as the database fields change.  The code should check for that.

Names can be anonymized by taking an MD5 hash  of the real name, effectively using it as a random seed for a randomized name (as in items and monsters in *Diablo*).  Likewise any other unique data.

If you need strong anonymization, discard *so many bits* that collisions are guaranteed to happen and effectively accounts get merged.  For instance I had to anonymize 200 million accounts, so I hashed the account ID and used only 24 bits.  200 million accounts fell into 16.7 million buckets.

Another option is to retain all real data, but do a hash-based shuffle of the relationship between, say, names and account numbers.  That lets you test against real names, complete with four middle names, first character being Unicode, newline in the last name, or whatever lives in your real DB.